# how to populate different records in row of a Grid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

Helo, I have a two Grid where I have to display some records from the table. The table consists of employee names ,manager names and their comments. Now on the first gird I am fetching data of employee names. Now on the second grid I have to display data of manager names and their comments. The data is on the same table.
On show button of the first grid it shows all the employees. then on AdvWebGrid.ClickLink or any selected user on the first grid , i have to display the manager names and their comments on the second grid. How can I do that ?
Hope my problem is clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you use hirarchy grid?mean when you click on employee name it open a grid just below that row?i think it will be best option for you as you can use datatable in one datatable fetch all employee from table and assign them to first datatable and in other datatable fetch all manager and comments after doing all this just assign both datatable two grid datasource and create a join between them and it will work perfectly...

links

http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/web-hierarchical-data-grid.aspx#Overview

http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1webparts/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fdisplayingahierarchicalgrid1.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407273(office.14).aspx

http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=21&pId=

Comment: Hi Emy, but I have to use TMS AdvWebGrid , no other choice.

Comment: my table consists of " employee manager1 manager2 manager3 .......
manager_comments " , now I have to populate manager1, manager2, manager3 on the second grid at runtime. Data which I am fetching on both the grids is from one table.

Comment: ok.so there is event named RowCommand use that event for first grid and when user click on that row check the index of cell get the id and pass it to query,query return data,save that data in datatable and assign that datatable to 2nd grid.all this work done in rowcommand okk.

Comment: mentioned not.........Have a good experience in VS......

vote my answer as you can see it on top of click tick by you.

Comment: hi Emy, how can I send a webform to different users.I have a webform where four different users will update some records and forward to each other.

Comment: sending webform? ican't understand your point..clarify your requirement.